# 2 pies in one figure with same legend and separate chart labels

Tags: tikz-styles, legend, charts, pgf-pie, pie

I'm trying to create 2 pie charts within the same figure. The problem is I want them both to have the same legend, but I cannot manage that. The package seems to assume that each individual pie needs a separate legend/label, and so wouldn't let me combine them.

Another question is that I would like to label the first pie Generation 1 (up the top) and the second pie Generation 2 (also up the top).

If someone could please help I'd be very grateful!

Thank you.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
% Gen1
\pie [polar, text = legend] {3/ Imperative , 20/ Interrogative , 65/ Main
, 12/ Subordinate}
% Gen2
\pie [polar, pos={8,0}] {4/ Imperative , 20/ Interrogative , 51/ Main
, 25/ Subordinate}
\end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How did you manage the pies without \usepackage{pgf-pie}--I could not!

Legend is common as I see-- so what is required there if you could elaborate?

[image]

Labes/Captions added at the top of both pie charts

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{datapie}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
every node/.style={align=center},
     pin distance=9mm
                    ]
% Gen1
\pie [polar, text = legend] {3/ Imperative , 20/ Interrogative , 65/ Main
, 12/ Subordinate}
% Gen2
\pie [polar, pos={8,0}] {4/ Imperative , 20/ Interrogative , 51/ Main
, 25/ Subordinate}

 \node (O) at (0,3){Caption 1};
 \node (O) at (8,3){Caption 2};
\end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

### EDIT1

To remove labels

```
\pie [polar, pos={8,0}] {4/ {} , 20/{} , 51/ {}  , 25/ {}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello, thank you for helping. I'd like all the labels of the second pie (Interrogative, Imperative, Main, Subordinate) disappear. As you probably see, the common legend is applicable to both charts, and hence the second charts' various labels are unnecessary.

Comment: see edit above -- simply delete the label entry and replace with empty braces `{}`

Comment: Great, thank you so much. I wouldn't have thought the solution was that simple!

Comment: please upvote the answer by clicking the up pointing triangle  on right side of answer if helpful

Comment: I did but here's the message I got `Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.'